# Java JAXB how to create POJO classes

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, pojo

With JAXB, how can I create the POJO classes with such a xml structure :

```
 <procedure>
    <procedure>
       <param>value1</param>
       <param>value2</param>
    </procedure>
    <procedure>
       <param>value3</param>
       <param>value4</param>
    </procedure>
 </procedure>
```

As you can see the external `procedure` tag is the same than the internal `procedure` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's so special about the outer/inner `procedure` element names?

Probably something like:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="procedure")
public class Procedure {
    @XmlElement(name="procedure")
    public List<Params> procedures = new LinkedList<Params>();
}
public class Params {
   @XmlElement(name="param")
   public List<String> params = new LinkedList<String>();
}
```

Untested.

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan I was not sure `Params` will be deducted from the generic `List<Params>` type.

Comment: sorry, I have to specify that the first procedure tag is not the root tag

Comment: @janvan777 You have asked a question, and have got an answer to that question. If you actually wanted to ask something different, please ask *another* question now. I'm reverting your edit as now my answer (and Blaise's correction) look incorrect. But it was your mistake, not ours.

Comment: sorry for the mistake, I will open another question. Thank you for your answers.