# Create POJO class structure using JAXB from XML

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, pojo, xjc

I have looked at below mentioned question:

[Java JAXB how to create POJO classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26822077/java-jaxb-how-to-create-pojo-classes)

[Java JAXB xml pojo classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26823002/java-jaxb-xml-pojo-classes)

Here is what I want to do.

I want to use JAXB and create POJO Java classes **at runtime**. If I change my XML in future, I don't need to make change POJO Java class structure manually. I need to only restart whole Java Application and it will generate all classes **at runtime without user input**

**FYI :-**

- using XJC is not helpful as i can not merge it into application.
- I have already automated whole business logic which is not affected by XML file.

Comment: r u talking about **generate classes in runtime** only?

Comment: @UUIUI , yes... I will edit question and make it easy to understand

Answer (score 0):

Here are some maven modules which you may find helpful

[jaxb2-maven-plugin](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.mojo/jaxb2-maven-plugin)

```
Mojo's JAXB-2 Maven plugin is used to create an object graph from XSDs based on the JAXB 2.1 implementation and to generate XSDs from JAXB annotated Java classes.
```

[maven-jaxb2-plugin](https://java.net/projects/maven-jaxb2-plugin/pages/Home)

```
This Maven plugin wraps and enhances the JAXB Schema Compiler (XJC) and allows compiling XML Schemas (as well as WSDL, DTDs, RELAX NG) into Java classes in Maven builds.
```

[jaxb2-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/jaxb2-maven-plugin/Documentation/v2.2/)

```
This plugin uses the Java API for XML Binding (JAXB), version 2+, to generate Java classes from XML Schemas (and optionally binding files) and to create XML Schemas from annotated Java classes
```

Comment: Correct link for the `maven-jaxb2-plugin` is https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin.